# Multiple Realms architecture

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a question regarding my architecture of multiple Realms in my project. Consider the following model:

```
@objcMembers class Book: Object {
    dynamic var bookID = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var year: Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "bookID"
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to either *like* a book or to put it into a shopping list. 
The first solution I came up with was to have three default Realms for:

- Books - `RealmBooks`
- Books liked - `RealmLiked`
- Books added to a shopping list - `RealmShopping`

With this fairly simple approach I was forced to have several Realms. In the future I would like to sync the data from the above Realms to the Realm Cloud. So to avoid this is it possible to have an architecture that combines the data of let's say `RealmLiked` and `RealmShopping`? This could be of an object type `UserSettings`:

```
@objcMembers class UserSettings: Object {
    dynamic var userID = UUID().uuidString
    let likedBooks = List<Book>()
    let shoppingListBooks = List<Book>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "userID"
    }
}
```

Then I would simply sync UserSettings and this would act like the master Realm. Obviously the remaining `RealmBooks` would be synced in a separate Realm. The reasons for all of this is due to trying to keep my project simple as well as the limitation of having [Up to 3 Realm Instances](https://realm.io/pricing) synced in the standard version of Realm Platform Cloud.

I would like to know the best practice in this scenario. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's not what "Realm Instance" means in the case of sync platform. Realm instance refers to the number of ROS servers that are running: afaik typically "staging" and "dev" and "production".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be sure, can you please elaborate on the meaning of 10,000 simultaneous connections, which is also stated at the standard version. Does this mean that if there are more than 10,000 users connected to ROS, I would have to go enterprise?